# Deduplication problems in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have one dataframe with many rows of id, date and other information. It contains **2,856,134** records. A count distinct of ID results in **1,552,184** records.

Using this:

```
DF2 = sorted(DF.groupBy(DF.id).max('date').alias('date').collect())
```

Gives me the max date per ID, and results in **1,552,184** records, which matches the above. So far so good.

I try to join DF2 back to DF where id = id and max_date = date:

```
df3 = DF2.join(DF,(DF2.id==DF.id)&(DF2.Max_date==DF.date),"left")
```

This results in **2,358,316** records - which is different than the original amount.

I changed the code to:

```
df3 = DF2.join(DF,(DF2.id==DF.id)&(DF2.Max_date==DF.date),"left").dropDuplicates()
```

This results in **1,552,508** records (which is odd, since it should return **1,552,184** from the de-duplicated DF2 above.

Any idea what's happening here? I presume it's something to do with my join function.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that some ID's have more than one record in the original data set with date = max_date, and/or records with no date at all?

Comment: try with inner join. left join shows all the id of left table. so Its same count as left table s count.

Comment: @sahildesai used inner join, got the same results.

Comment: oky then just add the condition... `where id is not null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its because  your table 2 has duplicate entries for example:

`Table1                Table2
_______               _________
1                      2
2                      2
3                      5
4                      6`

`SELECT Table1.Id, Table2.Id FROM Table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Id=Table2.Id`

Results:

`1,null
2,2
2,2
3,null
4,null`

I hope this will help you in solving your problem